# How can I easily find blogs by Stack Exchange users?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, search, users, blog

I would like to add more blogs to my reading list and since there are so many brilliant people writing answers on the Stack Exchange sites I figure a fraction of them might also write excellent blogs. However, going through users by reputation, new etc., clicking their website link (if any) is not very convenient.

What I search for is something that allows me to:

- filter users that have a website (if possible detect if its a blog)
- filter users by **tags** and stack exchange site [python]{stackoverflow}
- order users by different criteria (votes, related tags)
- let me go to their website without going into their profile

Is there such a service?

Comment: Not what you are asking for but there is http://blogoverflow.com which hosts blogs for Stack Exchange communities.

Answer (score 3):

I think your question actually belongs to [stackapps](https://stackapps.com/). Using the [SE API v2.0](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) you can get a list of [users](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users) and look at each [`user`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/user) object.

Those `user` objects hold among other fields, the `website_url`.

I can't help you get the entire application done but I can point you towards the right direction which I think it the SE API.

Comment: Thanks, was hoping to find an existing solution but will update if i throw something together =)